# Excel Data Connection - Unrecognized Database Format

Tags: database, excel, format, data-connections, microsoft-query

I have a data connection in several Excel documents that share the same source file on a shared network.  If one user opens the *source file* and another user attempts to refresh the data connection, the query fails and displays an `Unrecognized database format`.  It will then try to open the source file as a `Read-Only` copy.

There has to be a way to designate that the source file in this data connection is to be *Read Only*, and that it shouldn't matter if somebody else has the source file open.

I have tried a whole slew of different options, including a "ReadOnly" statement in the Connection String, adding `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`command, editing in Microsoft Query, etc.  Does anybody know how to force the data connection to retrieve the source file as *Read Only* and pull in whichever data was last saved even if the source document is open somewhere?

My OBDC Connection String is:

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ="File Path";DefaultDir="Directory Path";DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;ReadOnly=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Repair your MS-Office to sort out this problem.

Hope this will help you out.